# Explanation for str_replace("/", DS, $uploadTo)

Tags: php, html

what does the DS mean?

```
$upload_dir = WWW_ROOT.str_replace("/", DS, $uploadTo);
```

Comment: no idea what the rest of your code is, so there is no idea how we could know what `DS` is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the context, I'm going to take a punt and say the `DS` stands for 'Directory Separator'. Search your code, somewhere you will find a line like this:

```
define('DS',$someValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

DS is probably short for a predefined DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 1):

DS has to be defined as a constant somewhere before that line; `str_replace` takes three arguments:

**search, replace, originalString**

I suspect that DS in this case is a constant that means "directory separator."

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-str_replace.php

Answer (score 0):

It's a constant.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Dynamic-Links-with-DS-constant-td1268889.html